# Twitter API access to similar_to functionality?

Tags: api, twitter

Is there any way to programatically access, through the Twitter API or otherwise, the data from the list of handles from the similar_to page? (e.g. https://twitter.com/#!/similar_to/aplusk).

Scraping as always is least desirable with dynamic javascript sites like Twitter.

Comment: For what it's worth, [here's the JSON query backing the link you provided above](https://api.twitter.com/1/users/recommendations.json?cursor=-1&connections=false&pc=true&display_location=st-view-all-stream&user_id=19058681).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there, it's just currently undocumented:

[`https://api.twitter.com/1/users/recommendations.json?user_id=783214`](https://api.twitter.com/1/users/recommendations.json?user_id=783214)

Looking at the request, these parameters are supported:

- `connections`: Includes extended network connections in the data structure. For example,  `connections=true`
- `limit`: Limit the number of entries. For example, `limit=3`
- `user_id`: The user ID to get recommendations for. For example, `user_id=783214`

Twitter Web options:

- `cursor`: Unclear. I'd assume this removes the selection cursor in Twitter Web. For example, `cursor=-1`
- `display_location`: The location to display the results (for Twitter Web). For example, `display_location=st-view-all-stream`
- `pc`: Unclear. I'd assume this is just user-agent checking. For example, `pc=true`

It doesn't require authentication to hit against. I'm not sure if this is rate-limited, because I can't find any further information at the time of this writing.

While no documentation has been given by Twitter on this API, it's in current use by Twitter Web and Twitter Mobile for iOS, and it otherwise appears to be production-ready. Obviously, no guarantees can be had until Twitter officially releases it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There's also a thing you may remember since theres no API 1.0 you cannot make requests from javascript, jquery, ajax or client languages to json. You can only make requests just with server languages like PHP to json in API 1.1.

But let's think that you want to make your application more dynamic, if we cannot make request to twitter directly, the solution is that you have to use PHP auth with Twitter and then in your own page (with the response of the php page) make the Javascript, ajax, and you can make it dynamic like API 1.0.

my own application [Twitter API](http://twitter.infomundo.org)